# Max area of rectangle in an ellipse

Tags: optimization, conic-sections

I have an ellipse of shape

$\dfrac{(x-y)^2}{2m^2} + \dfrac{(x+y)^2}{2n^2} = 1$
Given that $0<mn \leq 1$.

Find the area of the maximum rectangle that could fit inside the ellipse.

Comment: sorry, I meant it goes from 0 to less than m multiplied by n to less or equal to 1.

Comment: I'd start with the change of variables $u=x-y, v=x+y$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please tell us about your attempts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Making a change of variables (rotation) as

$$
\left\{x\to \frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{Y}{\sqrt{2}},y\to \frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{Y}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}
$$

we get at

$$
\frac{X^2}{n^2}+\frac{Y^2}{m^2} = 1
$$

Now forming the Lagrangian

$$
L(X,Y,\lambda) = 4XY + \lambda\left(\frac{X^2}{n^2}+\frac{Y^2}{m^2} - 1\right)
$$

the stationary points are given by

$$
\frac{ \lambda  X}{n^2}+2 Y = 0\\
\frac{ \lambda  Y}{m^2}+2 X = 0\\
\frac{Y^2}{m^2}+\frac{X^2}{n^2}-1 = 0
$$

and solving we get at

$$
S = 4 X_0Y_0 = 2mn
$$

Comment: Is it possible to find m and n to find the exact area?

Comment: $m,n$ are the parameters which define the ellipse.

Comment: what happens if the sides of the rectangle are parallel to x and y axis

Comment: The question asks for the maximum rectangle that could fit.